# What is the best way to select a random vertex from Titan graph database

Tags: java, graph, graph-databases, titan

I need to select random vertex or edge from a graph. I am currently using blueprints API to query graph. What is the best way to randomly pick a vertex or an edge from my graph?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you don't know all your elements in your graph, you can use [getVertices()](http://www.tinkerpop.com/docs/javadocs/blueprints/2.1.0/com/tinkerpop/blueprints/Graph.html#getVertices%28%29) or [getEdges()](http://www.tinkerpop.com/docs/javadocs/blueprints/2.1.0/com/tinkerpop/blueprints/Graph.html#getEdges%28%29) to retrieve all vertices / edges from the graph.

But since you get an iterator from these methods, the actual problem is, *how to choose a random element from the iterator*.

There are two ways to solve this.

1. Iterate over all elements and store them in an Array or List and choose a random element by the size of the collection, or
2. Use [Reservoir sampling](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reservoir_sampling) while iterating over your elements.

---

There is another way to solve this if you use the [Gremlin Pipeline](https://github.com/tinkerpop/gremlin/wiki/Using-Gremlin-through-Java), performing your query based on your labels, using the [random filter from gremlin](http://gremlindocs.com/#filter/random) and select the first vertex.

Comment: I am currently getting all my vertices into an arraylist and then generating a random number between 0 and size of the arraylist. Arraylist.get(randomNumber) method is currently working but it is slow. I wanted to know if there is any other way to select random vertex. My requirement is to get random vertex among those with a particular edge(label property) or to query random edge with a particular label, so that I can get its vertex.

Comment: Then the second approach should fit your needs. You should use a query  like `graph.query().labels("foo").vertices()` and use Reservoire sampling to avoid the extra list to pick a random element from the iterator.

Comment: I am using titan graph database and I do not see ha method as lables()  for graph. "graph.query.labels("") is throwing compilation error". I have lables() method with vertex though(vertex.query().labels("")).

Comment: Yes you're right, that is only available on vertices. But the reservoir sampling should still do it's job with `getEdges()`.

Comment: I added another way, maybe this will help you.

Comment: I'm not sure `random` is as good a choice as [shuffle](http://gremlindocs.com/#transform/shuffle) in this case.  With `shuffle` you could just `next()` the first item found in the pipeline where `random` could require several evaluations before a random item is selected.

Comment: Thank you for replies!! Both random and shuffle are still being expensive. I am trying reservoir sampling now. Thanks again!